# access base routing using Router Provider in react-router-dom in application context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I want to show the modules in the right drawer based on the access in the JWT role like an admin can have access of 1 module and mutiple modules in my dashboard. how cann i implement the access based routing in my app where i am using Router provider of react-router-dom :

```
import routes from "@/global.routes";
import * as React from "react";
// import { OperatorManagementRoutes } from "./settings/operatorManagement.routes";
import { Token } from "@/components/Drawer/listData";
import { TOKEN_KEY } from "@/constants";
import { returnRoutes } from "@/utils/returnRoutes";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

/**
 * This is for dashboard routes.
 * All dashboard routes is used here.
 */

const MainLayout = React.lazy(() => import("@/layouts/MainLayout"));
const Dashboard = React.lazy(() => import("@/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard"));
const token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
let decodeJWT: Token | null = null;
if (token) {
  decodeJWT = jwtDecode(token);
}
export const DashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: routes.DASHBOARD,
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      ...(token && decodeJWT ? returnRoutes(decodeJWT) : []),
    ],
  },
];
```

and this is my returnRoutes file :

```
import { Token } from "@/components/Drawer/listData";
import { BannerRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/banner/banner.routes";
import { BrnachManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/brnachManagementRoutes/branchManagement.routes";
import { BrnachTimingsRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/brnachTimingsRoutes/branchTimings.routes";
import { CustomerManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/customerManagement/customerManagement.routes";
import { DispatchManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/dispatchManagement/dispatchManagement.routes";
import { KnowlwdgeManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/knowledgeManagement/knowledge-management.routes";
import { MarketingManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/marketingManagement/MarketingManagement.routes";
import { MenuRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/menu/menu.routes";
import { OrderManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/orderManagement/order-management.routes";
import { RadiusManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/radiusManagement/radiusManagement.routes";
import { RiderComplianceRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/riderCompliance/rider-compliance.routes";
import { RiderManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/riderManagement/riderManagement.routes";
import { SettingsRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/settings/settings.routes";
import { supportCenterRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/supportCenter/supportCenter.routes";
import { TicketManagementRoutes } from "@/routes/dashboard/ticketManagement/ticket-management.routes";

export function returnRoutes(decodeJWT: Token) {
  const routes = [];
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "MenuManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...MenuRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "OrderManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...OrderManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "BannerManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...BannerRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "CustomerManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...CustomerManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "RiderManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...RiderManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "TicketManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...TicketManagementRoutes);
  }

  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "BranchManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...BrnachManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "BranchTimingManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...BrnachTimingsRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "DispatchManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...DispatchManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "RadiusManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...RadiusManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "RiderComplianceManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...RiderComplianceRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "Settings"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...SettingsRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["SuperAdmin", "Admin", "CRM", "CrmExtended"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...supportCenterRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "KnowledgeManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...KnowlwdgeManagementRoutes);
  }
  if (
    ["Admin", "SuperAdmin", "MarketManagement"].some((role) =>
      decodeJWT.userType.includes(role)
    )
  ) {
    routes.push(...MarketingManagementRoutes);
  }
  return routes;
}
```

and each ...Route can contain this sample :

```
import GoBack from "@/components/GoBack/GoBack";
import routes from "@/global.routes";
import { DeliveryOrderRoutes } from "./delivery-order.routes";
import { PickupOrderRoutes } from "./pickup-order.routes";
import { PrintRoutes } from "./print.routes";
/**
 * This includes the Order Management routes.
 */

export const OrderManagementRoutes = [
  {
    path: routes.ORDERMANAGEMENT.INDEX,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <GoBack />,
      },
      {
    path: routes.ORDERMANAGEMENT.PICKUPORDER.INDEX,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <PickupOrder />,
      },
    ],
  },
    ],
  },
];
```

can any body tell if i am doing something wrong or missing any cause when i try to click on any option in drawer it shows this error :

````
@rollbar_react.js?v=08dd6b85:1852 No routes matched location "/dashboard/order-management/delivery-orders" ```

but when manually type in the search bar the route of that list item it drawer is opens
````